# SetLimitText not working for multiline in MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an edit text control which is represented as following in .rc:

```
EDITTEXT IDC_EDIT1, 26, 23, 60, 14, ES_RIGHT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
```

I tried un-restrict the limit lext using: `m_editCtrl.SetLimitText(0);`
but it is not working. If I remove '`ES_RIGHT`' from the *rc file*, it worked well.

Is there any way to to un-restrict the text limit for `ES_RIGHT`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(m_pEdit != NULL)
{
    CString strVal;
    //Get text value from the dit control
    m_pEdit->GetWindowText(strVal);

    //Get parent control
    CWnd* pParentHwnd = m_pEdit->GetParent();

    CRect ctrlRect;
    m_pEdit->GetWindowRect(&ctrlRect);
    pParentHwnd->ScreenToClient(&ctrlRect);

    DWORD dwStyle = m_pEdit->GetStyle();
    DWORD dwExstyle = m_pEdit->GetExStyle();
    CFont* pFont = m_pEdit->GetFont();
    int nCtrlID = m_pEdit->GetDlgCtrlID();
    DWORD dwSelection = m_pEdit->GetSel();
    CWnd* pWndPreviousCtrl = m_pEdit->GetNextWindow(GW_HWNDPREV);
    m_pEdit->DestroyWindow();

    if (dwStyle & ES_MULTILINE)
    {
        dwStyle &= ~ES_MULTILINE;
    }

    //Create edit control
    BOOL bIsCreated = m_pEdit->CreateEx(dwExstyle, _T("EDIT"), strVal, dwStyle, ctrlRect, pParentHwnd, nCtrlID);
    if (bIsCreated)
    {
        //Set window position to maintain z-order for tab navigation
        m_pEdit->SetWindowPos(pWndPreviousCtrl, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        //Restore font
        m_pEdit->SetFont(pFont);
        //Restore last selection
        m_pEdit->SetSel(dwSelection);

        if (bHasFocus)
        {
            m_pEdit->SetFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `ES_RIGHT` style doesn't play nice with `ES_AUTOHSCROLL`.

Looks like you can make it work if you create your edit control without `ES_RIGHT` style and later modify it like that:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->ModifyStyle(0, ES_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue is reproducible for ES_MULTILINE. Remove multiline from rc, it will solve the problem.